# rounded border around img

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

I want to make it as flexible as possible, so i split the png into left top corner, left, right top corner etc..

Here is what I have tried:

```
<div class="top">
<div class="lt">
    <div class="lr">
        <img src='somepicture.jpg' />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.win{width:182px;}
.win .lt{background:url('../img/5.png') no-repeat left top;}
.win .lr{background:url('../img/7.png') no-repeat right top;}
.win .top{background:url('../img/6.png')  top;}
.win .l{background:url('../img/2.png') no-repeat left;}
.win .top,.win .lt, .win .lr{height:10px;padding:0;margin 0;overflow:hidden;}
```

`.win .l` doesn't fit to the height of the image.

Maybe my whole approach is wrong. What's the best practice for such a problem?

/* EDIT */

it looks this solution doesnt work for me:

[image]

as u can sse the border is missing from the corners. if i make it 4+ px thick then its ok but i need it 1px thin. why it is a problem?

the **html**

```
<div class="win" >  
<img class="rounded" src='red.jpg' />
</div>
```

and the **css**

```
.win{width:188px;float:left;margin:0 30px 25px 0;}
.win .rounded {
overflow: hidden;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
border:1px solid #000;  
-moz-border-radius: 7px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 7px; /* Safari and Chrome */
border-radius: 7px; /* Opera 10.5+, future browsers, and now also Internet Explorer 6+ using IE-CSS3 */
}
```

Comment: how about using `border-radius`?

Comment: Border-radius is supported from IE9 and onwards, and in most other newer browsers. Firefox has it from Version 1.0 (!) if you use the -moz- prefix.

Comment: Where is `.win` and `.l` in your markup?

Comment: Also, where is the `text` in your markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using `border-radius`, which gives you rounded corners in all modern browsers:

```
.something{
   border-radius:4px;
   -moz-border-radius:4px;
   -webkit-border-radius:4px;
}
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius

You can use this tool to determine the size: http://border-radius.com/

**NB:** if you need support for IE<9, you can use http://css3pie.com/

Comment: i tried this and in my IE i didnt see the effect, thats why i went for the png solution. (i have IE 8)

Comment: "Border-radius is supported from IE9 and onwards..."

Comment: @PDFedit As mentioned in the comments above, `border-radius` is supported from IE9 on.  You can, as I suggested in the answer, use CSS3Pie to treat IE<9.

Answer (score 0):

Border radius really would be the nice way forward as it's simple and IE<9 just have to make do with a slightly less visually appealing site. Still, if you want to go with the corner image option see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/JS5AG/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img />
    <span class="tl"></span>
    <span class="tr"></span>
    <span class="bl"></span>
    <span class="br"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
}

span.tl {
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
span.tr {
    top: 0; right: 0;
}
span.bl {
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
span.br {
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack is for using border-radius in IE8 (and older) and its very fussy, 
First download this .htc solution: [Curved Corner](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/) and upload it to your site. Then wherever you need a border radius, apply this CSS:

```
.rounded-corners {
    behavior: url(/css/border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

**Use it as a last resort.**